# yii framework for php $this->redirect() function

Tags: php, redirect, yii

yii framework for php `$this->redirect()` function works great, it can redirect to external links, but when I use`æ, ø, å` characters in string, they are wrongly shown in the final url after redirect.

```
$this->redirect ("http://test.com?name=børing");
```

will redirect me to a page

```
test.com?name=bÃ¸ring
```

Help me to fix this issue

Comment: charset? maybe utf8_decode('børing')?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$this->redirect("http://test.com?name=" . urlencode("børing"));
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, whenn you add some explaination to your intension.

Answer (score 0):

So, i combined @zazu suggestion and first answer and this:

urlencode(utf8_decode($url));

Worked for me.